# How can I receive a data stream in web version of Agora.io sent from Unity version of Agora.io and vice-versa?

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

It appears as though the CreateDataStream and SendDataStream which are available in the Unity SDK are not available in the web SDK. Is there a method that I can use to send data back and forth between clients across Unity and Web versions of Agora.io?

I notice that the RTM SDK is not available for Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are correct, DataStream is not available for Web.  RTM SDK for Unity is on the product road map and it will soon be released in a month or so. Sit on tight and watch for the product announcement.

Comment: The RTM SDK is available now: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Unity-RTM

Comment: RTM seems to be a different system than WebRTC. If I just want to send simple data, without all chat functions like offline messages or history, from a web client to unity, I have to use RTM ? There is no plan to add DataStream to the webSDK ?